# how to set the cdn url using w3total cach plugin using wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

In W3total cache plugin:

I'm getting Url

> "http://d2vwmkksqncpb8.cloudfront.net/wp-content/themes/twentyten/images/headers/path.jpg" after uploadind cdn...

But i want the url like this

> "http://d2vwmkksqncpb8.cloudfront.net/foldername/wp-content/themes/twentyten/images/headers/path.jpg"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under the CDN configuration, in the "Replace site's hostname with" field you can enter a hostname with a path i.e.

"d2vwmkksqncpb8.cloudfront.net/foldername/"

Which will add the foldername into the path.